# Cannot override Bootstrap variables in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-sass

This is specific to Rails version 4.

I have a fie "custom.css.scss" and am using the bootstrap class' of "navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" followed by a div of navbar-inner and div container.

No matter where I put the variables, either before the include @bootstrap or after, I cannot change the black color of the Bootstrap inverse navbar.

Here is the first bit of my "custom.css.scss" file where I just try and set the whole damn thing to purple:

```
$navbar-inverse-color:                #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-bg:                   #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-border:               #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-link-color:           #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-link-hover-color:     #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-link-hover-bg:        #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-link-active-color:    #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-link-active-bg:       #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-link-disabled-color:  #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-link-disabled-bg:     #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-brand-color:          #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-brand-hover-color:    #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-brand-hover-bg:       #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-toggle-hover-bg:      #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-toggle-icon-bar-bg:   #9b59b6;
$navbar-inverse-toggle-border-color:  #9b59b6;


@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */
```

But, it stays exactly the same black (inverse) navbar. The other aspects of the styling (below where it comments for mixins, variables, etc) all work fine and I can change element colour and styling no problem.

I am using bootstrap-sass and sass-rails latest versions with Rails 4.0.3. I have been at this all day long and can see no way to change the bootstrap variables and thus my colours.

Very frustrated and hope someone can help :)

EDIT: Sharing code that gives the navbar (header)

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class ="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to 'Tracker', root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "About",   about_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", "#" %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Overriding the variable won't change  navbar style you have to use it in your stylesheet. For eg: if you want to change the navbar background then you can do something like <code> .navbar-inverse{background:$navbar-inverse-bg;} </code>

Comment: Your code looks alright. Variables should be set before `@import "bootstrap"`. Can you share the code where you are using the `navbar-inverse`? Also, is bootstrap loaded in the application correctly, do you see it applied on other elements?

Comment: Deep: That made no difference, it's still exactly the same black inverse navbar I'm afraid :(

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?  I'm having the same experience.  Thanks.

Comment: Funny, I copied your code, dropped it in, and it worked just fine...  I have much the same environment.  Thanks.

Comment: I gave up completely in the end, due to this and other problems getting bootstrap to do anything consistently - I switched to Foundation, which does what you expect it to in a logical manner. Bootstrap sucks and never works as intended as far as all my experience with it went.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the variable context/scope is lost.  You need to make sure you only import the **underscored** files directly, then your variables will be recognized.

**non-underscored** imported scss/sass files will begin their own variable context/scope, ignoring anything above it.

The latest bootstrap top-level file in the version I checked 3.3.1 is `_bootstrap.scss`.  This is a recent change (old was `bootstrap.scss`) and I just had to update some project build files when upgrading from 3.1.1.  In this case, you may just want to update your bootstrap-sass dependency and it might just start working for you!

Comment: I know stackoverflow won't let me comment with 'thanks' but THANKS you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're referencing and have configured the Bootstrap gem ('bootstrap' or 'bootstrap-sass'), create a file in the app/assets/stylesheets folder with a name that will that will cause it to load before 'application.scss' (such as '_custom_variables.scss').

Inside this file, before anything else, import "bootstrap/variables", (as specified in the '_bootstrap.scss' file within the gem.) and then make your customizations. This is the 'one little detail' that isn't emphasized in the docs!

Note that these are only **Bootstrap variable overrides**, your 'regular' customizations will still be in 'custom.css.scss' after Bootstrap has loaded.

Next, reference your customization file in 'application.scss' before the @import "bootstrap" statement.

Example:

In your variable customization file, _custom_variables.scss:

```
// app/assets/stylesheets/_custom_variables.scss
@import "bootstrap/variables";
$body-bg:    $gray-dark;
$body-color: $gray-light;
```

In application.scss:

```
// app/assets/sytlesheets/application.scss   

// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "custom_variables";
@import "bootstrap";
```